# Using Should and Does

Tags: grammar

Why do the words "Should or Does" impact the conjugation of its following verb? For example

> My brother *gets* up in time.
>
> My brother should *get* up in time.
>
> My brother does *get* up in time.

The simple conjugation of the verb should be

> I *get*
>
> You *get*
>
> He, she, *gets*

Why does using the word *should* or *does* change the conjugation of the verb?

Comment: Why are you writing "get" like that with quotation marks?

Comment: You only need one marker for tense and person. When you have a helper verb, that's the one that takes that marker. The main verb then stays in the infinitive. "She *gets*", "he *got*"; "it *has*". But "she does *get*", "he did *get*", "it doesn't *have*". Now, modal verbs like *should* don't have a marker for person, but that's a separate issue altogether. "I should, we should, he should" — it is always the same. But that doesn't affect the main verb. It has to be in the infinitive because you're using a helper verb. And so it stays in the infinitve no matter what happens to that helper verb.

Answer (score 1):

Because *does* and *should* are verbs themselves - auxiliary verbs in this case - and they conjugate according to subject. They then take a bare infinitive, the primary verb, the one they are auxiliary to.

So:

> I get up
>
> He gets up

and

> I do get up
>
> He does get up

Answer (score -1):

***Should get up*** means it is something that ought to happen, but it has not happened yet. The person is still in bed or still sitting down:

> She should get up so I can make the bed!

***She does get up*** is similar in meaning to ***She gets up***, except you are emphasizing that this is an event that is happening. It implies that you are wondering whether or not she got up yet. For example:

> If she does get up, tell her to make her bed!